# Cannot Open Specified file

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with VBA. I have two workbooks, one with student's list name and their age and second with some files (Hyperlinks). Each files in second workbook contain student's information depends on age (from 5 to 10 years old) and those files are in column A (A1,A6). So, I want to search each student's information in workbook2 by student's name in workbook1.

I don't want to search one by one, I want to use loop and Copy all student's information that met condition.

Note: student name in second workbook don't contain in order like first workbook. And it can has two names (so I want to copy all match name).
Sorry that I cannot write English in appropriate words.

My problem is that I cannot open Hyperlink using loop . 
This is the code that I use to open hyperlink:

```
Activeworkbook.FollowHyperlink _Address:=Cells(j,1), NewWindow:=True
```

- `Cells(j,1)` refer to Files in colum A. 
  Does anyone have solution ? Sorry for my mistake

Comment: Please have a look at [ask] and [mcve] and improve your question accordingly.

Comment: ... and how does your code look like? Can you show us the complete command you've used?

Comment: Addition, I want to open it by Loop.

Comment: Hi Dominque, my code here:                                    Activeworkbook.FollowHyperlink _Address:=Cells(j,1), NewWindow:=True

Comment: Could you edit your question with the code you've written please - the edit button is just under the tags.  Could you post enough code and explanation so we can reproduce the problem.  At the moment I'd hazard a guess that `Cells(j,1)` is empty or not on the sheet you think it is.

Comment: Yes, I will try to explain my condition now.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your URL has `"http://"` or `"https://"` prefixed.